# Can I use Pentax screwmount lenses on my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, lens-adapter, old-lenses, screw-mount

Can I use my old camera lenses of Ashahi Pentax SP1000 screw mount in my Nikon DSLR D60 camera? If possible, where can I get the necessary accessories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pentax screwmount (M42 Mount) lenses on a Nikon D60 (F-Mount) by using an adapter. An example of such an adapter is this one available from B&H Photo:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/995104-REG/fotodiox_m42_nk_pg_pro_nikon_f_mount_lens.html